# Close Angular Material menu on custom backdrop events

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a menu on my site that places a backdrop on the whole site. The menu can be closed by clicking anywhere, but on the menu, which works great.

My issue is that on mobile devices the backdrop is only removed when a tap event occurs, but not on swipe. Some of our users can't figure out what they should be doing to make the site responsive again.

A couple of solutions that came to mind, but I don't really like:
- Turn off the backdrop and add a "Close menu" button to the menu. I guess this would be fine as a last resort.
- Add a class to the backdrop, and "grey out" the whole site when the menu is open. This doesn't look very nice in our current design, however.

I think the best solution would be to close the menu on swipe/scroll as well. Can I bind these events somehow to the backdrop?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try installing hammer.js for dealing with such events

---

[image]

Comment: Sure, if it helps. Just looked into HammerJS, I guess I could add a backdrop class, find the backdrop DOM element by class and attach an event with HammerJS? I have very strong jQuery vibes from this solution, seems a bit hacky in Angular, but I could try this, thanks.

Comment: mat menu there are panelClass where you can customize it

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, but I'm not sure how this helps me. To customize the backdrop I'd have to use backdropClass, not panelClass as far as I know, but even then this doesn't really help me customizing when the menu is closed.

Comment: https://material.angular.io/components/menu/api There are `@Input('class')
panelClass: string` and `hasBackdrop: boolean | undefined` you can use for overriding backdrop behavior

Comment: Also you can override these class in your global styles.css/scss `cdk-overlay-backdrop cdk-overlay-transparent-backdrop cdk-overlay-backdrop-showing`

Comment: Sorry, maybe my question isn't clear. The backdrop is added dynamically. When the user clicks on it, the menu closes. I have to extend this in a way, that the menu closes on touchstart and mousescroll events as well, however, the backdrop DOM element is not available in my component, so I can bind these event directly.
I still don't see how adding classes and custom css can help me here.